# How to use my own pre-existing table for authentication in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent, laravel-8

I installed **auth in laravel 8** but I don't want to use the default table dedicated for authentication **Users** because I have my table **Users_inf** in this case I can't use migration,  **Users_inf** also has 200 records.
**Users_inf**(user_id, password, user_name,privilege,active,CREATED_AT,UPDATED_AT).
*CREATED_AT and  UPDATED_AT* added by me to be compatible with laravel.
I am using user_name for login not email. please, any suggestion for that issue.

Comment: You can change model provider at config/auth.php Look for 'model' => App\User::class, and change it to your class e.g. App\UsersInf::class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I see it, you have two choices. Either alter the `users` table to have those fields, then import the data from one table to another - or, update your `User` model to use that table. In any case, you have to instruct Laravel to use the `user_name` field for authentication. Personally I would recommend going the first route, as that's the "Laravel way".

#### Approach 1: Altering the users table

Alter the migration of the `users` table, something along the lines of this. I would recommend you keep the ID field `id` rather than specifying your own `user_id`, as this is - again - the Laravey way of doing things.

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('user_id'); // $table->id();
    $table->string('user_name')->unique();
    $table->string('privilege')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->boolean("active")->default(true);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then to move the data over, run the following SQL query

```sql
INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name, privilege, active, password, created_at, updated_at)
    SELECT user_id, user_name, privilege, active, password, created_at, updated_at
    FROM users_inf AS ui
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                      FROM users AS u
                      WHERE u.user_name = ui.user_name)
```

Now you just need to instruct Laravel to use the `user_name` field, which we cover at the bottom of this answer.

### Approach 2: Altering the User model

Laravel lets you specify which table and which field is the primary key, by adding simple properties to the model. Inside your `User` model class, add the following two lines,

```php
protected $table = 'users_inf';
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

### For both approaches: Using the `user_name` field as the login

Simply add the `username()` method to the `User` model class that returns the field which Laravel should use to lookup users in the given table.

```php
public function username()
{
    return 'user_name';
}
```

---

Laravel will give you so much "for free" and a lot of features will work more seamlessly when using the proper naming conventions. I suggest you follow the Laravel standards and naming conventions, as it will make it easier to work with the framework as a whole.

Comment: Thank u, I will try your approaches.